# How to use Fragments and RecyclerView?

Tags: javascript, android, xml

I am a student beginning coding my coursework using Android Studio. I am rather new to it and have been using YouTube tutorials to help which doesn't have much explaining in them.

I have tried to merge the two together and for the most part have been successful, the issue is now it is telling me that I need to incorporate a `RecyclerView` into my `activitymain.xml` but I have already created it as nav view inside that file so I'm unsure how to do it.

The two different tutorials create a navigation menu using fragments and also a card view which I am trying to out into one of my fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/draw_menu" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need navigation menu to be able to build recyclerview.

There are a few steps to make recyclerview and fill it with data.

**1 inside your layout (activity or fragment) use**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycles"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
```

**2 in your (activity or fragment) you will need to setup an array and layout-manager something like this :**

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   binding.returnSelectedRecyler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    binding.returnSelectedRecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    binding.returnSelectedRecyler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**3 build layout that you show in every row inside your recyclerview**

**4 build an adapter that will connect everything together**